# What is the indexing strategy for a variable query?

Tags: mongodb

The most common use case for this would probably be a user table, with name, lname, email, phone.

I might search for name contains "paul", email contains 2@yahoo"

I might search for phone = 01234567890

I might search for email = "foo@bar.com"

It is my understanding that in a mongo index works in order.  So an index that looks like
name:1, lname:1, email:1, phone:1 wouldn't work for any of the above queries?

What's the best indexing strategy to account for search tables like this?

Comment: you should take a look at MongoDB Atlas Search. You can do this really easily there with a wild card index. Would you like a sample query.

Comment: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/path-construction#wildcard-field-search

Comment: @Nice-Guy Yes please, that looks like what I'm looking for!

Comment: If you want features like autocomplete and things, you could achieve all those with Atlas Search. So, just keep me posted on if the  approach below is in the right direction.

Comment: I also added the query you proposed. This would work pretty well for you. If you were frequently updating your documents, you would need to be ok with eventual consistency. For most search queries that is ok. The data should replicate relatively fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, paul you will need to create an index definition before you can run the query. Creating your first search index definition in the collection view in Atlas Data Explorer can be tricky.

Here's what I would recommend for an index definition based on those docs:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "fields": {
      "email": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "phone": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "name": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "lname": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
        "type": "string"
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I would recommend for a contains-style query on the email and name fields:

```
  { 
       $search: {
        index: 'default',
        compound: {
          must: [{
            wildcard: {
              query: '*paul*',
              path: 'name'
              }
            },{
            wildcard: {
              query: '*2@yahoo*',
              path: 'email'
            }
        }]
      }
   }
}
```

Should be a lightning fast query, even for a large index, and as one of multiple clauses as you have described. Let me know if you have any more trouble. There's lot of features like highlighting that should be helpful as well. Note that this query is a single clause. If you want multiple clauses as you have described, embed this clause in a `compound` operator as seen [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound).

Comment: This is brilliant thank you.  I'll give it a go but it looks exactly what I'm looking for